# elementos por arriba y por debajo de la diagonal secundaria de una matriz en java

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber como puedo imprimir los elementos por arriba y por debajo de la diagonal secundaria de una matriz, por ejemplo:
si la matriz es:

`1 2 3 
 4 5 6
 7 8 9`

Los elementos por arriba son: `1 2 4`

Los elementos por debajo: `6 8 9`

Hasta ahora el código que tengo es este, pero no me da los resultados que espero:

Elementos por arriba:

```
for(i = 0; i<L1; i++)
{
    for(j = i; j<L1; j++)
    {                   
        if(i*j==0)
        {
            System.out.println("|" + Matrix1[i][j] + "|");
        }
    }
}
```

Elementos por debajo:

```
for(i = 0; i<L1; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<i; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("|" + Matrix1[i][j] + "|");
    }
}
```

Comment: en tu código `if(i*j=0)` no va a funcionar nunca, tienes que poner `==`. Un igual para asignación y dos iguales para comparación

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar la condicion del if en comparaciones lo tienes como `=` y debe ser `==`. En segundo lugar segun el codigo que das puedes optimizarlo en un mismo if no hace falta recorrer la matriz dos veces con dos bucles for. Te pongo un ejemplo en javascript que funcionaría igual que Java en este caso.

Esto me temo que solo sería valido para una matriz de nivel 3 y para una de nivel 4 podria no funcionar pues habria que modificar las condiciones del if, se podría hacer seguro una lógica que valga para cualquier tamaño de matriz aunque sería mas complejo y tampoco se si lo necesitas

```js
const Matrix1 = []
Matrix1[0]=[1,2,3]
Matrix1[1]=[4,5,6]
Matrix1[2]=[7,8,9]
let L1 = Matrix1.length;

for(i = 0; i<L1; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j<L1; j++)
    {                   
        if((i*j==0 && i+j<2) || ((i==L1-1 || j==L1-1) && i+j>=3))
        {
            //System.out.println("|" + Matrix1[i][j] + "|"); use this in Java
            console.log("|" + Matrix1[i][j] + "|");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una respuesta que sirve para cualquier matriz cuadrada, primero me fijo si estoy sobre un elemento de la diagonal secundaria y luego imprimo todos los elementos que se encuentran debajo de el.

```js
const Matrix1 = []
Matrix1[0] = [1, 2, 3]
Matrix1[1] = [4, 5, 6]
Matrix1[2] = [7, 8, 9]
let L1 = Matrix1.length;

for (i = 0; i < L1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < L1; j++) {
        if (j == L1 - 1 - i) {
            let aux = i;
            while (aux < L1 - 1) {
                console.log("|" + Matrix1[aux + 1][j] + "|");
                aux = aux + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui te dejo para ver por arriba de la diagonal secundaria, lamento la demora, ahora recorro la matriz desde abajo hacia arriba y de izquierda a derecha espero te sirva

```js
const Matrix1 = []
Matrix1[0] = [1, 2, 3]
Matrix1[1] = [4, 5, 6]
Matrix1[2] = [7, 8, 9]
let L1 = Matrix1.length;

for (i = L1-1; i > -1; i--) {
    for (j = L1-1; j > -1; j--) {
        if (j == L1 - 1 - i) {
            let aux = i;
            while (aux > 0) {
                console.log("|" + Matrix1[aux - 1][j] + "|");
                aux = aux -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: esto es justo lo que necesito, pero ¿como haría para mostrar los elementos del lado opuesto de la diagonal? ¿invertir el ciclo?

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi solución. **NOTA:** solo funciona para matrices cuadradas por eso se incluye la función para verificar si la matriz no es cuadrada.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] L1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};

        for (int i = 0; i < L1.length; i++) {//imprime la matriz
            for (int j = 0; j < L1[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.print("|" + L1[i][j] + "|");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (cuadrada(L1)) {
            superioresDiagSec(L1);

            System.out.println();
            inferioresDiagSec(L1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("La matriz no es cuadrada");
        }

    }

    private static void superioresDiagSec(int[][] L1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < L1.length; i++) {//imprime los elementos por encima de la diagonal secundaria
            for (int j = 0; j < L1[i].length - i - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print("|" + L1[i][j] + "|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void inferioresDiagSec(int[][] L1) {
        int a = 1;
        for (int i = L1.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {//imprime los elementos por debajo de la diagonal secundaria
            for (int j = a; j < L1.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("|" + L1[i][j] + "|");
            }
            a += 1;
        }
    }

    private static boolean cuadrada(int[][] L1) {
        boolean cuadrada = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < L1.length; i++) {
            if (L1.length != L1[i].length) {
                cuadrada = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cuadrada;
    }
```

La idea para solucionar el problema de los elementos superiores es recorrer la matriz fila por columna `- 1` cada vez para acotar el final y para los elementos inferiores es comenzar la lectura desde la ultima fila hasta la primera utilizando el mismo principio, y la columna iniciando una columna después cada vez iniciando en la columna que no cubre la diagonal.

**Salida:**

[image: Salida en consola]